# Allow others to sell my products?

Tags: api, drupal, e-commerce, prestashop, affiliate

I'm in the process of developing a eCommerce site around Drupal/Prestashop or another similar one.

Is it possible to integrate an affiliate type feature that allows users to sell my products on their website? So for example, 'approved users' would login to a sub-section of my website and select the products they want to include, and copy some source onto their site. If so how complex would be to integrate or develop a script/system like this?

Answer (score 0):

first decide what affiliate network you want to be a part of. If u decide to run your own affiliate system. Once you decide that then look at the below

https://www.drupal.org/project/affiliate
https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_affiliate2
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_affiliate